# Conduction Angle of Class C amplifier

Tags: rf, pspice, power-amplifier

I have this circuit of class C amplifier and want to set up its conduction angle at 45 degree. Could any one help me to what should I do[image]?

Comment: What are the waveforms in the picture?

Comment: Green is sine input and red is output. In the circuit picture voltage marker places is visible.

Comment: And the voltage scales? Please add this information to your question and not in comments. What conduction angle waveform are you expecting? Maybe draw a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In class C amplifier, amplifying action take place just for a degree period less than 180. I want to set it at 45 degree.

Comment: Try feeding the base with a pulse waveform with 12.5% duty cycle.

Comment: Adjust the base bias.